# iOS Facebook how to get suggested friends like Hangtime or DrinkAdvisor

Tags: ios, facebook, friend

I saw in Hangtime app or DrinkAdvisor app, when I used Facebook to register & login, and in Friends tab, I can see list of Suggested Friends, I guess this list include people that I interract often, ie: like their photos, chat with them ...
I'm not sure how they can get that list?
Would you please help?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook doesn't provide an endpoint that returns such a list.

We (Hangtime) calculate the list ourselves using the data from the Facebook stream and analysis of the mutual friend graph.

A simple algorithm can get you most of the way there. Getting it to give good results across a wide variety of users can be difficult depending on how you define a suggested friend in your app. It can also require a fairly large number of API calls for each user.

The most basic version is to sum up the number of interactions between a user and each friend on the Facebook stream and do a descending sort. Facebook published a paper recently with an interesting algorithm using only social graph analysis: [Romantic Partnerships and the Dispersion of Social Ties:
A Network Analysis of Relationship Status on Facebook](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.6753.pdf)

Comment: Thanks for your response. Would you please let me know the simple algorithm that you are talking about?

Comment: @kenvu Allan did tell you a version of what you're asking for: *"The most basic version is to sum up the number of interactions between a user and each friend on the Facebook stream and do a descending sort."*  Beyond that, you're asking for their proprietary code, which I very much doubt they'll share.